# angular js, passing data as parameter from view to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parameters, push

I'm tryng to get data from view that must be passed as parameter in a function to populate an array in the controller. 
But the objects return me nothing, here what i have done:

**VIEW**

```
        <div ng-repeat="cssframework in voce.framewrok">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-onchange="AggiornaTotale({{cssframework.costo}})"/>  
        <span>{{cssframework.name}}........<b>{{cssframework.costo | currency}}</b></span>
      </div>    
<div class="row">
    <h3>TOTALE: {{selectedVoices[0]}}</h3>
</div>
```

ng-onchange trigger the function "AggiornaTotale" and pass cssframework.costo as parameter, the goal in the controller, is to populate an array named "selectedVoices"

**CONTROLLER**

```
    $scope.AggiornaTotale = function(param) {
    $scope.selectedVoices = [];
    this.selectedVoices.push(param);
}
```

Why i don't see {{selectedVoices[0]}} updated?
Thank you for advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
ng-onchange="AggiornaTotale({{cssframework.costo}})
```

to

```
ng-change="AggiornaTotale({{cssframework.costo}})
```

and controller to

```
 $scope.AggiornaTotale = function(param) {
    $scope.selectedVoices = [];
    $scope.selectedVoices.push(param);
 }
```

Comment: cool, it works.
but can you tell me why <b>{{cssframework.costo | currency}}</b
disappear?

Answer (score 2):

replace `ng-onchange` with `ng-change`

Comment: and `ng-change` works only if `ng-model` exists on same tag

Comment: yep i see, now if i check it change the model too